# sublime unable to save mounted files

Tags: node.js, ssh, sublimetext2, sshfs

**edit**: it turned out that the hard drive of my dev box is broken.

**original**:

I do this every day, but it suddenly down today. I tried restart.

1. I mount to my devbox

   ```
   sshfs -o cache=yes root@zh*****:/var/www www
   ```
2. Then I

   ```
   ssh root@zh*****
   ```

   and go to www/app open sublime there and edit files

The problem is whenever I want to save file, Sublime says "Unable to save ~/www/app/**.js"

Also I can't open files on devbox through vim.
And also I got this connection error when I try to run my node server on devbox (which never happened before). I'm not sure if this is related but they happened together.

```
$node-dev app/start.js
Server started on port: 3000
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/todo-app-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:26)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/todo-app-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:41)
    at Connection.connect (/var/www/todo-app-api/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/todo-app-api/app/start.js:39:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object..js (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-dev/lib/hook.js:52:17)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: Starting log most probably is not connected to the saving issues you're facing

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your files have correct permissions set up.

IIRC everything you do through `sshfs` by default is made via user `fuse`, so I would try connecting to `sshfs` as a concrete user without cache (remove `-o cache=yes`) and your user's `uid` and `gid`. You may also change the encryption algorythm to something faster as this is a dev box. This can be done by:

```
sshfs -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o ssh_command="ssh -Cc arcfour256" root@zh*****:/var/www www
```

Replace the `uid` and `gid` from your user on the server:

1. Do `cat /etc/passwd` on the remote machine
2. Find your user, will be something like `root:x:1000:1000:,,,:...`
3. First integer is the `uid` and the second one is `gid`.
4. Replace them and try remounting sshfs